# How to use Application.OpenForms in c#

Tags: c#

In a c# project how to use "Application.OpenForms"
how it use in the project, for identify a Form is already open or not...
can you show me a example.

Comment: Can you detail what part of the documentation of OpenForms and FormCollection doesn't fulfill that?

Answer (score 0):

```
Timesheet ts = (Timesheet)Application.OpenForms["Timesheet"];
ts.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => ts.dataGrid3.DataSource = null));
```